# Minimum slope of a chord to parabola

Tags: geometry

A line is drawn from  $(-2,0)$ to intersect
$y^2 = 4x \,\,$ in P,  Q within the first quadrant, such that

$$ \frac{1}{AP} +\frac{1}{AQ} < \frac{1}{4} $$

Find the minimum value of the line slope. A is the origin.

I had basically let the coordinates of the parabola in parametric form and then used the given condition, but couldn't find the minimal slope.

Comment: What is $A$, the point $(-2, 0)$? Using what you tried, were you able to make any progress, or did you get stuck somewhere?

Comment: @pjs36 when I used the condition of sum of reciprocal of distances I couldn't simplify it to get any relationship with the slope

Comment: I don’t believe that there is such a line. If you parameterize it by its slope $m$ then for $0<m<1/\sqrt2$ (the upper bound is the slope of the tangent through $(-2,0)$), $1/\sqrt6 \lt 1/AP+1/AQ \lt 1/2$.

Answer (score 3):

As it is stated  in the  current form, this problem - as shown below - has no real solutions. I suspect that the original formulation might have been slightly different, in particular with $A$ indicating the point $(-2,0)\,\,$ and maybe with a more general equation of the parabola (again see below). In this answer, I will assume that $A=(-2,0)\,\,$ and that $P$ and $Q$ are distinct points. Also, I will firstly consider the case of the specific parabola described in the OP, and then the case of a more general parabola equation. Lastly, I will add a brief comment on the case where $A$ is the origin.

Since the line crosses the point $(-2,0)\,\,$, it has the form

$$y=ax+2a$$

The intersection points of this line with the parabola have $x$-coordinates given by

$$ \frac{2 (1 - a^2 \pm \sqrt{1 - 2 a^2})}{a^2}$$

whereas the $y$-coordinates are

$$ \frac{2 (1 - a^2 \pm \sqrt{1 - 2 a^2})}{a}+2a$$

Calculating the length of $\overline{AP}$ using standard formulas yields

$$\overline{AP}= \left[\left( \frac{2 (1 - a^2 - \sqrt{1 - 2 a^2})}{a^2} \right)^2+ \left(\frac{2 (1 - a^2 - \sqrt{1 - 2 a^2})}{a}+2a \right)^2 \right]^{1/2}$$

which can be simplified as

$$\overline{  AP}=\frac{2 \sqrt{2 - 2 a^2 - a^4 -2 \sqrt{1 - 2 a^2}}}{a^2}$$

In a similar manner we get

$$\overline { AQ}=\frac{2 \sqrt{2 -2 a^2- a^4 + 2 \sqrt{1 - 2 a^2}}}{a^2}$$

Note that since we must have $1 - 2 a^2 >0\,\,\,$ to have two separate intersection points, we get the condition

$$-\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} < a <   \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}  $$

to obtain a different real value for $\overline{AP}$ and $\overline {AQ}$.

Substituting the expressions above in

$$\frac{1}{\overline{AP}}+\frac{1}{\overline{AQ}}<\frac{1}{4}$$

and simplifying, we get

$$\frac{1}{2 \sqrt{1 + a^2}}<\frac{1}{4}$$

whose positive solution is

$$a>\sqrt{3}$$

Because this solution has no intersection with the range of $a$ needed to have $AP$ and $AQ$ real,  we conclude that there are no real values of $a$ that satisfy the conditions stated in the OP.

Notably, after some searching, I found on Google a nearly identical version of this problem with no solution but four possible answers ($<\sqrt{3}\,\,$, $>\sqrt{3}\,\,$,   $\geq \sqrt{3}\,\,$, none of them),   with the only difference that the initial parabola has equation $y^2=4kx \,\,$. The point $A$ is explicitly defined as the point $(-2,0)\,\,$. This more general version of the problem is interesting because, after calculations that are similar to those shown above, it leads to the same final inequality $1/(2 \sqrt{1 + a^2})<1/4\;$ with solution $a>\sqrt{3}\,\,\,$ (in other words, in the final part of the calculations and simplifications, $k$ is canceled out). In contrast, $k$ is not canceled out in the condition necessary for $AP$ and $AQ$ to be distinct and real, which becomes

$$-\sqrt{\frac{k}{2}} < a <   \sqrt{\frac{k}{2}}  $$

allowing to find, for $k>6\,$, an intersection between this range and that stated in the solution, and giving the answer $a>\sqrt{3}\,$ as the inferior bound of the slope. Note that such condition, for $k=1\,\,$, is the same obtained above considering the problem for the specific parabola $y^2=4x\,\,$.

Lastly, repeating the same calculations for the case where $A$ is the origin leads to similar results. The final inequality in this case yields the numerical solution $a>1.23414...\;$ (apparently with no closed form). Again, because of the condition needed for $\overline{AP}$ and  $\overline{AQ}$  to be real and distinct, there are no real solutions for the case with parabola equation $y^2=4x\,\,$. On the other hand, in the general case with parabola equation $y^2=4kx\,\,$, there are real solutions only for

$$k>2\cdot 1.23414...^2=3.04620...\,\,\,\,$$

and the numerical solution $a>1.23414...\,\,\,$ is the lower bound of the slope.

Answer (score 1):

Convenient to shift reference to origin

$$y^2= 4(x-2) $$

Convenient to use polar coordinates

$$(x,y)= r ( \cos \theta, \sin \theta) $$

Plug in

$$ r^2 \sin^2 \theta =4 ( r \cos \theta-2)$$

Simplify, let me abbreviate for easier Latex typing

$$ 4 r s_t^2 -4 r c_t +8 =0 $$

If roots are $r_1,r_2 (AP,AQ) $ for quadratic, sum and product are

$$ r_1+r_2= 4 c_t/s_t^2$$

and

$$ r_1\cdot r_2= 8/ s_t^2$$

Trick is to divide getting

$$ \frac{1}{ r_1} +  \frac{1}{ r_2} = c_t/2 $$

( BTW harmonic mean of the two segments $ AP,AQ = 4 \sec \theta $ )

Now if $$ c_t/2<\frac14$$

then for maximum slope

$$ t= \pi/3, m= slope= \sqrt3$$ 
Next find slope of tangent onto parabola from origin for maximum possible slope, we find intersections between
$$ y^2= 4(x-2) ,\quad y=mx$$
Plug in and get quadratic in, say $x$.

$$ m^2x^2 -4x +8=0$$
Discriminant is zero for tangent condition
$$ \Delta= 16- 4\cdot m^2\cdot 8 =0 $$
of tangent line L2
$$ m= tangent slope = \pm \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$$
For given slope line L1
$$ \sqrt3 > \frac {1}{\sqrt 2}$$
So given inequality *can never be satisfied with the real* numbers.
All the above are included together in a single graph below:

[image]

For line $L1$ neither the segments nor their harmonic mean exist in reals.